# Debian 12 - Adding a secondary IP doesn't seem to work

Tags: networking

I followed most of the guides out there for adding an extra IP assigned by my provider. The extra IP is the 172.93.104.**

I set up my `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
allow-hotplug enp36s0f1
iface enp36s0f1 inet static
        address 104.194.11.**/24
        gateway 104.194.11.*
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

iface enp36s0f1 inet static
        address 172.93.104.***/24
        gateway 172.93.104.*
```

I am unsure what to do here, that `allow-hotplug` has me confused the most, instead of `auto eth0` or something like that.

This is my `ip a`output, well part of it:

```
6: enp36s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:fa:06:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 104.194.11.**/24 brd 104.194.11.255 scope global enp36s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.93.104.***/24 brd 172.93.104.255 scope global enp36s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d250:99ff:fefa:62d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

With these settings, I am unable to ping the IP. Should I have changed the `enp36s0f1` to `enp36s0f1:1`?
Maybe I should've assigned it to a new interface like `eth0` for example? I don't know...

Comment: You can only have 1 standard gateway. From where did you ping the host (the originating IP)? what does `ip route` say?

Comment: Using multiple gateways requires at least policy routing. Can you provide a link to your host provider's documentation for additional IP addresses (sometimes they are called failover IP address)? That's because each provider has its own quirk to follow.

Comment: Just checking what I could find about ReliableSite tells that there should be a virtual MAC address associated to the additional IP address. So this probably can't be done on the same interface (again: in addition to the multi-homed routing problem requiring more work). Documentation would really be needed.

Comment: Adding a second IP-address to your interface did work! Your `ip address show` output shows three lines starting with `inet` for your device. Two of these show IPv4 addresses and they match your setting in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

However, you cannot simply give a computer two equivalent Internet uplinks and expect it to do the right thing. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure you need a secondary IP address? Why are you asking it? The setup can change slightly based on your needs.

Comment: You need to use netplan and iproute2 so several interfaces could have each its own gateway